# How to securely delete/wipe out a hard disk so it's hard to recover data?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, shredding

as I am new Linux user I don't really know yet where's path to my disk, so therefore also I don't know how to wipe out data from it.

As I mentioned I would need something that will wipe out a hard disk, so I did a bit of googling and I found out that something like command `shred` will most likely suit me.

Now, I found out that this is syntax of command:

```
shred [OPTIONS] FILE [...]
```

So, I would probably run shred with these options:

```
shred -vfzu -n 25
```

Now back to my problem, I don't know what's the path of my hard drive, because I have exactly 4 `sda` parts in `/dev/`, and they are:

```
sda
sda1
sda2
sda5
```

So, my question here is which one of these should I even shred? And how can I know it's the right one?

Comment: sda1 is partition 1 on drive sda, sda2 partition 2 on drive sda etc.... It very much depends on what you want to shred and only you know that....

Comment: You should **shred the whole drive (disk), that is `/dev/sdx`**, where `x` is the device letter, in your case `a`. You should be very careful, because that drive letter may change, and if you get it wrong, you might destroy valuable data. - `shred` can do the job, but many people claim that it is overkill to overwrite several times. It is **enough to overwrite with zeros once**, which you can do with other tools, and it will be faster, and cause less wear of the hardware. You can use **Disks** alias `gnome-disks` or [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb).

Comment: @Bruni Ahh, alright gotcha...

Comment: @sudodus So using shred would affect HDD? Thanks for info btw

Comment: @str1ng, Shred will overwrite the data on the drive or partition, that you tell it to shred. And you get the best result, when you overwrite the whole disk (drive in linux terminology).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `shred /dev/sda` will shred the whole disk from the first to the last sector, so everything, including partition table will be erased.
- shred `/dev/sda1` will shred the first partition on the disk. This will destroy the filesystem in this partition, the partition table entry for this partition remains.
- `shred /dev/sda2` will shred the second partition on the disk. If this is an extended partition which acts as a container for `sda5`, then `/dev/sda5` will be completely erased, but the partition table entry for `/dev/sda2` remains.
- `shred /dev/sda5` will erase the contents of this partition, the partition itself will remain.

Of course, you will need root privileges, so use `sudo` or run as root. Very helpful might be a command like

```
lsblk -f
```

wich will give you sufficient information about your devices.

Since shredding the whole drive or a partition which is currently in use will most probably end with unwanted side effects, consider booting from USB.

Comment: Thank you, this was super detailed and useful. Can you explain me more on how exactly does it affects HDD?

Comment: We are writing to files here, but this files are not regular files like text files, this are files representing block-devices such as your HDD or the partitions on it. `/dev/sda` represents the diskspace from the first to the last sector. The others represent the partitons, disk-space from sector x to sector y as defined in the partition table (which resides in `/dev/sda`). So when you shred a partition, you only shred the content of the partition, but nothing changes in the partition table which is stored in the first sectors of `/dev/sda`.

Comment: Ahhh, okay gotcha.

Answer (score 3):

### General

All these actions should be performed when booted from another drive for example a USB drive.

You should **erase the whole drive, that is `/dev/sdx`**, where `x` is the device letter, in your case `a`. You should be very careful, because that drive letter may change, and if you get it wrong, you might destroy valuable data.

### HDD and `shred`

`shred` can erase the data on a HDD, hard disk drive, but many people claim that it is overkill to overwrite several times. It is **enough to overwrite with zeros once**, which you can do with other tools, and it will be faster, and cause less wear of the hardware. You can use

- **Disks** alias `gnome-disks` or
- [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb).

### SSD (and HDD) connected via SATA or NVME

If you have an SSD connected via SATA or NVME, you should avoid using the tools above. Instead you should use the built-in tool to remap the links between the logical memory locations and physical memory cells. This can be done via the command line tool `hdparm` in Ubuntu. This works like advanced encryption, where the key is thrown away and is much faster and causes much less wear compared to overwritng.

A fairly new hard disk drive (HDD) connected via SATA can also be remapped using `hdparm`.

- Lock the drive with `hdparm` and the option `--security-set-pass`
- Erase the drive with `hdparm` and the option `--security-erase`
- Unlock the drive with `hdparm` and the option `--security-unlock`

See `man hdparm` for more details.

### SSD (and HDD) connected via USB

Warning: Using the built-in tool via **`hdparm` is very risky and should be avoided**, when the drive is connected **via USB**.

### USB pendrive and memory card and other drives connected via USB

You can use

- **Disks** alias `gnome-disks` or
- [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)

to wipe the whole device of a USB pendrive or memory card and other drives connected via USB.

- A HDD connected via USB can also be wiped with `shred` as decribed above.

Comment: This was really in-depth! 
Thank you for your explanation!

Answer (score 0):

- sda is the entire disk
- sda1 is the first partion of that disk and so on.
- sdb is the second disk
- sdb1 is the first partition of the second disk and so on.

To wipe the entire disk with all partiontions, use the entire disk - sda.
To wipe a specific partition, specify the partiotion - for instance sda2.

Disk device names can differ on different systems.

Shred is an excellent tool but be warned, it is really easy for an unexperienced user to wipe the wrong partition or disk. If so you loose your data permanently.

BTW, 25 passes will take a long time to complete. I'd change that to 1 or two if it's not Top Secret information we are talking about.

For solid state drives (SDD) you should use the ATA secure erase function of the disk. This will erase the entire disk. The reason for not using shred is that modern SDD disks distributes disk writes over the entire disk in order to prolong the life of the disk. Sadly this means that it is hard to securely overwrite data.

Follow this guide in order to perform an ATA secure erase :
[ata.wiki.kernel.org](https://ata.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/ATA_Secure_Erase)

Comment: Ohh alright, so if I want to delete everything I should just specify /dev/sda ...
Well, in case I do use shred, I will certainly want to delete everything, I might change it to 5 passes with option to overwrite it with 0's ... 

Thanks!